# Elementary neutral fermions cannot be deflected in an inhomogeneous magnetic field?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, fermions

Can we say that elementary neutral fermions cannot be deflected in an inhomogeneous magnetic field? In other words, is it true that if a neutral particle is deflected by an inhomogeneous magnetic field, it cannot be elementary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as neutrinos are [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and fermions and have a small mass as proven by the oscillations, people are working on calculating  the [magnetic dipole moment of the neutrino](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1506/1506.01284.pdf) for cosmological uses. So  the statement cannot be true.

The reason for the calculations is that interactions of elementary particles, even if neutral and only weakly interacting have feynman diagrams contributing to the crossection that have virtual loops of charged particles and thus a magnetic moment can be generated, which will exist in the interaction with the field you propose, even if it is very very small.

[See the history](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06883) of the neutrino magnetic moment. Note paragraph 2.

> For a Dirac neutrino, the chiral properties of neutrino magnetic moment and
>   neutrino mass are the same.